# Google Compute Engine new Ubuntu instance cannot login

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have just created a new GCE VM Ubuntu instance using the most basic way it is possible, and I cannot login to it.

When I opened the interactive serial console -> Serial port 1 using the browser, I am not logged in and it prompts me for a login. Also it said "creating account exampleaccount" right before the login prompt - signs of hope :)

exampleaccount happens to be my name before the @ sign of my google account.
When I attempted to login using exampleaccount I cannot, because I don't know the password, nor I remember setting it somewhere.
Also I did try my google account's password, I did try blank. I did try inputting exampleaccount@gmail.com as my username. Again no success.

I cannot login to the Linux VM I created. Please help howto.

Comment: You first have to ssh to it using your ssh key, then you can set a password if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, logging with it works and then you can set password with sudo passwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to SSH into the VM instance. Once you are connected to the VM instance via SSH, you can create user accounts with a user name and password. Once this is done, you will then be able to connect via the serial console port. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connecting_to_a_serial_console_with_a_login_prompt) is an article that provides to the steps you need to follow to connect to the serial port with login using a Linux image.